# Copy all files, subdirectories, attributes, etc. preserving ALL file info in legal forensic setting

Tags: android, google-drive-api, backup, robocopy, computer-forensics

The main point of my questions centers on copying ALL information (including as much metadata as possible) from my Normal Data Storage external drive to my On-Site Backup external drive using my Windows 10 laptop and file explorer as the transfer agent.

Here are the details of my setup and reasons for my current setup (if you need/want it):

- Setting/context: I am working on a court case. I have to assume the data I am using will be used as evidence in a court case and will be examined by a computer forensic specialist so I would like to preserve as much of the file and directory metadata as I can. Note: that is why I am being so verbose here.
- Cost constraints: I need a quick on-site and cloud solution under about $200 a month, that is why I am doing it the way I am currently.
- Current system setup: two 12T WD easystore external drives and Google Drive. This seems to be working.
- Backup goal: to have built-in redundancies. One backup in the cloud, one backup on-site, and one daily-use normal data store.
- Devices: Both the daily-use / Normal Data Storage and the On-Site Backup devices are 12T WD easystore external drives. The On-Site Backup always disconnected and stored in a secure location in the same building as my Normal Data Storage external drive. My Normal Data Storage stays connected to my laptop at all times and is automatically / dynamically backed up on Google Drive (cloud) as files are saved to it. My laptop backup image backs up directly to the Normal Data Storage external drive. I regularly "dump" data (all data not just media) manually to my Normal Data Storage from video cameras, cell phones, SD cards, thumb drives, etc. ("other devices") using a manual copy and paste via windows file explorer. I also save Windows Step Recorder files recorded on my laptop to Normal Data Storage. I record video using a laptop built-in camera and separate webcam directly to my Normal Data Storage device.
- Relevant Network: At this time, because I needed a quick and dirty solution, I connect everything to my laptop via USB 3.0 cords to do my file transfers between all devices using my laptop and Windows File Explorer as the transfer agent, a manual process. Google Backup and Sync to Google Drive uses a 5G WIFI connection which seems to do the job. All devices are scanned for threats before connecting to laptop. Other security measures are taken on the network and site that I have not mentioned for security reasons.

Put another way:

- Laptop backup image --> via normal Windows 10 image backup -> Normal Data Storage
- Files from "other devices" --> via saving directly -> Normal Data Storage
- Cell phones backed up --> via Android --> Google Drive / Google 1
- Normal Data Storage --> via Google Backup Sync (automatic/on all the time) --> Google Drive / 1 (10T)
- Normal Data Storage --> via Copy and paste (manually once a week) --> On-site Backup

Suggestions for a better setup welcome.

Note, we have grown out of the "manual" copy and paste method. I am working on simplifying and speeding up the process using `ROBOCOPY` or `copyx` via a batch (.bat) file kicked off manually once a week by a non-technical assistant, so it needs to be pretty bombproof and easy.

I am working on this right now, but here is where I am right now with replacing the "manual" copy and paste method from Normal Data Storage to On-site Backup mentioned above, I have yet to try `copyx`:

```
ROBOCOPY d:\src f:\dest /MIR /COPY:DATSOU /DCOPY:T
```

...via batch/.bat file.

Additional notes: Eventually, I want to connect all or some of the "other devices" to my laptop, click one button or file and have the script transfer everything (not just media files) from "other devices" to my Normal Data Storage, and then if my On-site Backup is connected have it backup Normal Data Storage to On-Site Backup after all is transferred from the "other devices" to my Normal Data Storage. So in theory, the script would look for connected devices, identify them from a list of devices that are allowed to be "dumped" and dump them then back them up.

If there is a better way to backup data on-site and in the cloud that costs less than $200 per month, and you  don't need regular IT support for, please let me know. Currently, the way I am doing it costs $99 per month, but the file transfer method I am using is cumbersome and prone to user error.

I am familiar with and have used Datto as a on-site and cloud backup solution, but they cost a lot and right now we are a small operation.

Thank you for your help. My central question is there there with a lot of detail. Please suggest a place to ask about my general setup if there is a good place to post that question on SO.

I will edit this post/question as I progress with code.

**EDIT 1** (Noted 2020-04-17 1142 MST):
This seemed to work and preserved my file modified dates. Not sure if there is way to capture more meta data or not:

```
ROBOCOPY d:\ f:\ /MIR /COPY:DATSOU /DCOPY:T
```

Currently reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy

**EDIT 2** (Noted 2020-04-17 1158 MST):
**Still need help!** The method in EDIT 1 overwrites files that have changed on the destination drive that have the same file name. I would like it to add new files to the destination drive preserving both the source drive file and the destination file (that has changed) along with all available metadata.

**EDIT 3** (Note 2020-04-17 1228 MST):
It looks like you can do multi-threading to speed this up via `/MT[:N]` found in the link above. What is a good way to determine how many threads you should use? The default is 8, so I was thinking of doing that. What is the best way to kill this process while it is running if the process is taking too long and you need to restart it later?

Comment: What does this have to do with Android programming?

Comment: The setup of what I am doing involves android. And maybe there is a better way to do some or all of this via Android programming. (At least that is what someone told me, hence the tag.)

Comment: `copying ALL information (including as much metadata as possible) from my Normal Data Storage external drive to my On-Site Backup external drive using my Windows 10 laptop and file explorer as the transfer agent.`. That has nothing to do with Android. And this is a programming site.

Comment: In order for the evidence to be admissable in court, you will need to maintain a chain of custoday if you are located in the US, and similarly other regulations may apply elsewhere. Using professional software like FTK Imager, Encase, etc. would be advised. If the case is very important, you would be better off hiring a forensics professional.